# access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: no)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Почему не происходит повторного соединения с БД? Оба метода используют статический метод подключения к БД. По отдельности работаю, но когда нужно получить информацию из БД как в примере, то первый запрос срабатывает, а второй нет и выдает ошибку. Почему во второй раз не получается подключиться к БД?

Пример кода:

```
    $categories = [];
    $categories = Category::getCategoriesList();
    $latestItems = [];
    $latestItems = Product::getLatestProducts();
```

Comment: А покажите класс, в котором создаёте pdo подключение и описываете методы.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin
Класс для подключения к БД
`class Db
{

 public static function getConnection()
 {
  $params = include_once ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
  $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'],$params['password'],$params['options']);
  return $pdo;
 }
}`
массив с опциями,возможно в них дело?
`
 'options' => array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC  
  )
 );`

Comment: Далее из базы тянем вот так, в обоих случаях практически идентично
`
$db = Db::getConnection();
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM category ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC");
  $result->execute();
  $data = $result->fetchAll();
`

Comment: @KirillKorushkin
Здесь не понятно получилось
ссылка на BitBucket
https://bitbucket.org/IvanphpII/error-bd/commits/ef36f4173bc83e22af079c15817fb8e62d0ab214

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке у вас во второй раз подставляются пустые переменные в подключение БД, проверьте по коду в методах почему не доходят данные или может в первом методе в их чистите и по этому по втором методе их нет.

Я бы вам советовал лучше делать подключение где то в начале скрипта, а в методы передавать переменную $mysqli или аналогичную вашу с уже активным подключением.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было при передаче параметров использовать *include* вместо *include_once*

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148455)